# Does Apple DeviceCheck still work on a jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: android, ios, security, safetynet, devicecheck

Simple question, no biggie.

I'm trying to secure a React-Native application by validating tokens on the backend that were generated by Android SafetyNet and Apple DeviceCheck. I then create an access token to the API after the device passes the attestation/device check on the backend.

My question is, could a hacker bypass Apple's DeviceCheck (and Google's SafetyNet) and still generate a valid token from Apple's API despite the fact that the device is jailbroken?

Answer (score 0):

If a device passes Apple's `isSupported` check, it is eligible to get the key back from Apple.

Ideally, you should use some code obfuscation tools like [arxan/digital.ai](https://digital.ai/) which provide static Jailbroken and Dynamic Instrumentation checks. Using this you should aim at obfuscating the code which contains [generatekey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573913-generatekey) and [attestkey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/dcappattestservice/3573911-attestkey) calls.

**Why obfuscate these 2?**

`generatekey` - Replacing with the keys owned by the adversary can compromise the rest of the cycle.
`attestkey` - Prevent Replay and prevent attestationObject portability.